# Linear Algebra in curved space

Tags: linear-algebra, recreational-mathematics, mathematical-physics

We know that Euclidean geometry and Newtonian Physics are special cases that only work in a flat space-time. Got to thinking about linear algebra and matrices. Is linear-algebra a special subset of some math? And does LA only work because our local space-time is flat enough to discard any discrepancies that would result from plotting a "line" or a "plane" in a curved space-time?

Comment: So you think that linear algebra has to do with physical space? It hasn't. It deals with vector spaces, linear maps, numbers and matrices. Whether it can be applied to make mathematical models of physical phenomena is something which is outside the scope of linear algebra.

Comment: Thought exp. If I have two lines that meet in flat space I have no guarantee that they will meet at the same point in curved space. Similarly, I think, If I have three equations of a plane, and I want to know where they meet in 3-Space I can do this easily in a flat space, but curve space either way and now the those same 2d surfaces do not necessarily intersect in the same "location".  Or am I not following you?

Comment: In the real world there are no lines and planes. Have you ever seen one?

Comment: a line being a vector on a surface and a plane being a surface yes I have....but that could be a naïve world view. But we know that a vector on a curved surface is a curve, similarly a surface must warp in curved space.... at some level. So I guess I was wondering if there is an algebra that compensates for these warps.... A "curvilinear" algebra if you will.

Comment: You might be interested in learning about manifolds.  I haven't read it but the book [Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms: A Unified Approach](http://www.amazon.com/Vector-Calculus-Linear-Algebra-Differential/dp/0130414085) by Hubbard and Hubbard could be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword is *Linearization*. Since anything in Physics is an approximation, things that are not linear, from a foundational point of view, may nevertheless be considered *as if they were linear*, as a first approximation. Especially in technological applications, where robustness is more important than exactness (e.g. classical electronics), this is common practice. See: [Linearization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearization) (Wikipedia).